# changing a php while loop to foreach

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and still getting used to the syntax.  Would anyone be able to tell me how I could re-write this block as a foreach instead of a while loop please?

When running an SQL query that would return two rows, I'm only getting one and I'm thinking it's to do with the type of loop that I'm using.

I'm having trouble getting syntax that works.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `staff_details` WHERE first_name='{$_POST['firstname']}' AND surname='{$_POST['lastname']}'");
<?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['role']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['grade']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that 'role' and 'grade' are indeed the right column names used in the database? Also, remember to close the while loop `<?php } ?>` after the table row <tr>. Everything else looks right.

Comment: The `while` is not the problem here so changing it to `foreach` will not fix your problem.

Comment: My apologies, it turned out that the statement was alright... some idiot (me) had placed an extra space in one of the names, thus not finding it.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `staff_details` WHERE first_name= ? AND surname= ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'])); //prepare statements
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row as $r){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $r['role'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $r['grade'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `staff_details` WHERE first_name='{$_POST['firstname']}' AND surname='{$_POST['lastname']}'";
$result = $db->query($q)->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $key) :
//do some actions
endforeach;
```